# Внедрение списка зависимостей с помощью контейнера Castle.Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

В качестве IoC-контейнера используется Castle.Windsor.

Корневой элемент приложения - планировщик `Scheduler`, который выполняет в определенной последовательности различные задания. Задания реализуют интерфейс `IWorker`, поэтому я решил внедрить(inject) `List<IWorker>` в `Scheduler`(список заданий). Впоследствии, планируется много различных типов заданий, сейчас их два: `Cleaner` и `Writer`. `Cleaner` нужен в одном экземпляре, используем Синглтон. 
Необходимо правильно внедрить N экземпляров `Writer`, где N - количество XML файлов в поддиректории приложения. Каждый из XML-файлов надо десериализовать и передать в качестве входного параметра каждому `Writer`у. Т.е. надо внедрить в `Scheduler`имплементацию для каждого XML. Как это правильно реализовать? Вообще какой паттерн используется в таком случае? Фабрика?

Конфигурация контейнера Castle.Windsor:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
// Для внедрения List
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel, true));
// Регистрация Scheduler
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IScheduler>().ImplementedBy<Scheduler>);
// Регистрация Workers...
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IWorker>().ImplementedBy<Writer>());
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IWorker>().ImplementedBy<Writer>());
// ...количество зависит от количества файлов + каждому надо передать десериализованный XML в качестве параметра
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IWorker>().ImplementedBy<Cleaner>());
// Забираем Scheduler
var sched = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
```

`Scheduler`:

```
public class Scheduler : IScheduler
{
    public IList<IWorker> Workers { get; set; }

    public Scheduler(IList<IWorker> workers)
    {
        Workers = workers;
    }
}
```

`Writer`:

```
public class Writer : IWorker
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public Writer()
    {
    }

    public Writer(string source)
    {
        Source = source;
    }
}
```

`Cleaner`:

```
public class Cleaner : IWorker
{
    public Cleaner()
    {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Дополнительный вопрос:

Содержимое Xml-файлов переехали в одну из таблиц БД. В `Scheduler` (корневой компонент) нужно внедрить по `Writer`у с параметром на каждую запись в таблице. Из полезного совета в ответе(Andrew Prigorshnev), следует, что обращаться к БД будет правильным после настройки контейнера и получения из него корневого компонента.

С точки зрения архитектуры, правильным ли будет внедрить в `Scheduler` компоненты: `WriterFactory`и `Repository`(слой доступа к БД), после чего получить экземпляр `Scheduler`, затем в нем с помощью `Repository` получить список параметров, а потом сделать на каждый параметр по `Writer`у с помощью `WriterFactory`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю в наиболее общем виде вопрос состоит в следующем: *как правильно внедрить список зависимостей с помощью контейнера Castle Windsor?*

Ответ следующий. Сам подход с внедрением списка через конструктор вполне корректный и ***Castle Windsor*** умеет работать с такими сценариями. Чтобы внедрить список зависимостей надо сделать следующее:

1. Зарегистрировать в контейнере резолвер списков. Вы это уже сделали в строчке `container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel, true));`
2. Зарегистрировать в контейнере несколько компонентов, которые должны быть внедрены в виде списка. При этом если вы внедряете список типа `IList<IWorker>` контейнер добавит в список все компоненты типа `IWorker`, которые вы зарегистрируете. Это вы сделали частично. В вашем примере не учтено, что когда вы регистрируете несколько одинаковых компонентов они должны быть именованными (делается с помощью метода `.Named()`), и по всей видимости вы не знаете как внедрить строку в конструктор компонента - это делается с помощью метода `.DependsOn()`

Таким образом правильная реализация вашей задачи должна выглядеть вот так:

```
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        // Для внедрения List
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel, true));

        // Регистрация Scheduler
        container.Register(Component.For<IScheduler>().ImplementedBy<Scheduler>());

        // Writers
        container.Register(Component
            .For<IWorker>()
            .ImplementedBy<Writer>()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("source", "files/first.xml"))                
            .Named("firstWriter"));

        container.Register(Component
            .For<IWorker>()
            .ImplementedBy<Writer>()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("source", "files/second.xml"))                
            .Named("secondWriter"));

        container.Register(Component
            .For<IWorker>()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("source", "files/third.xml"))
            .ImplementedBy<Writer>()                
            .Named("thirdWriter"));

        // Cleaner
        container.Register(Component.For<IWorker>().ImplementedBy<Cleaner>());

        // Забираем Scheduler
        var scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
```

И еще несколько замечаний, касающихся конкретно вашей реализации:

1. Вы хотите передавать в воркеры xml, но это плохая идея. Тогда вам придется прочитать его из файла прямо в корне компоновки, в том месте где вы настраиваете контейнер. Но чтение из файла это отдельная задача, никак не связанная с разрешением зависимостей, поэтому делать ее в корне компоновки не стоит. Пусть этим занимается один из ваших компонентов. В связи с этим, в примере кода выше вы можете увидеть что во Writer'ы передается путь к файлу, а не его содержимое.
2. Если файлы, которые вы обрабатывате меняются редко и их имена и количество известны на этапе написания кода, пример приведенный выше может вас полностью устроить. Но если это не так, надо сделать еще немного дополнительной работы, и как вы правильно предположили, надо использовать фабрики. Возможное решение здесь следующее. Надо добавить новую абстракцию - поставщик воркеров, который будет представлять собой фабрику, создающую воркеры:

   ```
    public interface IWorkersProvider
    {
       IEnumerable<IWorker> GetWorkers();
    }
   ```

Поставщик Cleaner'ов будет просто возвращать один Cleaner.  А поставщик Writer'ов может получать как аргумент конструктора путь к папке, в которой надо искать файлы, и затем в методе `GetWorkers`создавать по одному воркеру на каждый найденный файл:

```
public class WritersProvider : IWorkersProvider
{
    public WritersProvider(string folderPath)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<IWorker> GetWorkers()
    {
        // здесь создаем по одному воркеру на каждый найденный файл
    }
}
```

При такой архитектуре ваш Sheduler должен получать вместо списка воркеров, список поставщиков воркеров:

```
public class Scheduler : IScheduler
{
    public Scheduler(IList<IWorkersProvider> providers)
    {
        // здесь надо опросить все поставщики, чтобы сформировать
        // список воркеров
    }
}
```

Регистрация такой конфигурации в Castle Windsor делается с помощью тех же методов, что и регистрация в первом примере, поэтому не буду здесь ее описывать.

**UPDATE:** Ответ на дополнительный вопрос

Лучше сделать так:

1. В `Scheduler` внедрить список поставщиков воркеров (`IEnumerable<IWorkersProvider>`), как описано выше
2. Внедрить `Repository` в конструктор `WritersProvider` и уже во `WritersProvider`опрашивать базу данных

Идея здесь вот в чем. Каждый класс должен выполнять одну единственную задачу. Задача Scheduler-а взять готовый список воркеров и *запустить* их. Задача поставщиков воркеров - *создать* воркеры на основе какого-то правила (из xml-файлов, таблиц бд и т.д.). Разделив обязанности таким образом, вы получите код, который легко модифицировать. Если вы захотите поменять что-то в логике *запуска* воркеров, вы прийдете и поменяете только один класс - `Scheduler`, при этом вы будете уверены, что вы никак не сломали логику *создания* воркеров, потому что эту работу выполняют совсем другие классы.

Потенциально у вас может быть множество поставщиков воркеров, работающих по разным правилам. Один поставщик может всегда возвращать один и тот же жестко закодированный воркер, второй создавать по воркеру на каждый xml-файл в какой-нибудь директории, третий создавать воркеры на основе таблицы в базе данных, четвертый получать список воркеров, которые надо создать, у удаленного сервиса и т.д. Более того, в процессе развития проекта у поставщика воркеров может меняться  правило, по которому он создает воркеры (у вас это уже произошло -  вместо xml-файлов у вас теперь таблица в бд.)

Если поставщику воркеров для выполнения его работы нужен доступ к бд, внедряйте `Repository` прямо в поставщик. Если потом это правило изменится, прийдете и поменяете только конкретный поставщик, не трогая другие поставщики и не трогая `Scheduler`.

Вариант с фабрикой похуже, но тоже годится. Но если будете внедрять фабрику воркеров то `Repository` внедряйте уже в нее, а не в `Scheduler`.

Фабрика хуже, потому что, когда количество воркеров вырастет, вы все равно будете вынуждены разнести создание воркеров разных типов по отдельным классам, иначе фабрика будет слишком большой и запутанной. В итоге вы все равно создадите несколько фабрик (что полность аналогично моему варианту со списком поставщиков воркеров, отличие только в названии, фабрика и поставщик в данном случае одно и то же).

Comment: благодарю за развернутый ответ! Все нужно и по делу.

Comment: @ValeO рад, что удалось помочь

Comment: прошу обратить внимание на дополнительный вопрос

Comment: снова спасибо за помощь!