# Продвинутое внедрение зависимостей с помощью Castle.Windsor

Tags: c#, наследование, dependency-injection, интерфейс, внедрение

О простом внедрении зависимостей, а также внедрении списков с помощью Castle Windsor подробно расписано в ответе на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423428/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-castle-windsor) вопрос. Теперь я столкнулся с более сложным сценарием.

Есть интерфейс `IPipeline`.
Его реализует базовый класс: `PipelineBase : IPipeline`.
В свою очередь его наследуют два класса: `FishPipeline : PipelineBase` и `OctopusPipeline : PipelineBase`.

У меня есть два класса-потребителя, в которые нужно внедрить приведенные выше:

В первый класс `LargeAquarium` нужно внедрить и `FishPipeline` и `OctopusPipeline`.
Во второй класс `TinyAquarium` нужно внедрить только `FishPipeline`.

Каким образом это сделать? Нужно дополнительно вводить интерфейсы `IFishPipeline` и `IOctopusPipeline`?

**UPDATE:**

В общем, я сделал так: с учетом того, что `OctopusPipeline` имеет дополнительный функционал, которого нет в `IPipeline`, в любом случае нужно делать `IOctopusPipeline`. Получилась следующая схема:

`IOctopusPipeline: IPipeline` (не знал, что так можно)

`PipelineBase: IPipeline`

`IOctopusPipeline: PipelineBase, IOctopusPipeline`

Затем внедрил так:

```
 _container.Register(Component.For<IOctopusPipeline>().ImplementedBy<OctopusPipeline>());
```

Так работает, хотя, я при такой схеме начинаю путаться..

Comment: `IPipeline` - это трубопровод?

Comment: Именно он) Это из TPL Dataflow терминология, для понятности добавил рыб)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если интерфейсы не приносят никакой пользы, а только создают лишние сложности, я бы их просто убрал бы и сделал как-то так:

```
public abstract class PipelineBase { }
public class FishPipeline : PipelineBase { }
public class OctopusPipeline : PipelineBase { }
public class LargeAquarium
{
    public LargeAquarium(IList<PipelineBase> pipelines) { }
}
public class TinyAquarium
{
    public TinyAquarium(FishPipeline fishPipeline) { }
}

...

var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel, true));
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().Pick());
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<PipelineBase>().WithServiceBase().Configure(c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)));

var tinyAquarium = container.Resolve<TinyAquarium>();
var largeAquarium = container.Resolve<LargeAquarium>();
```

Comment: Хм, а ведь и впрямь.. хорошая идея, спасибо.